# Python 3: Passing functions into *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm using the `_thread` module (because it better fits in my program) and I want to pass a function into the function I'm passing into the thread. But, it's possible to pass only ***tuples*** into the `_thread.start_new_thread()` function, however, function is not iterable!

---

@Willem Van Onsem - here's the full code. Uses Pygame.

```
class PGMaster:
    """
    Properties:
    mainloopOn - exits program if False

    Functions:
    PGMaster.mainlooprunner()
        Repeatedly runs Main function (must be overrided).
    PgMaster.mainloop(subthread=False)
        Wrapper for mainlooprunner. Subthread - will it run under MainThread? No if True.
    """

    def winmode(self, dimensions, flags=0, caption='', depth=None):
        """
        Flags are:
        pygame.FULLSCREEN    create a fullscreen display
        pygame.DOUBLEBUF     recommended for HWSURFACE or OPENGL
        pygame.HWSURFACE     hardware accelerated, only in FULLSCREEN
        pygame.OPENGL        create an OpenGL-renderable display
        pygame.RESIZABLE     display window should be sizeable
        pygame.NOFRAME       display window will have no border or controls
        """
        if depth != None:
            screenx = self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions, flags, depth)
        elif depth == None:
            screenx = self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions, flags)
        pygame.display.set_caption(caption)
        return screenx

    def __init__(self, dimensions, flags=0, caption='', depth=None):
        self.winmode(dimensions, flags, caption, depth)
        self.mainloopOn = True


    def mainlooprunner(self, function):
        func = function
        while self.mainloopOn:
            func()

    def mainlooprunnerx(self, *function):
        func = function[0]
        while self.mainloopOn:
            func()

    def mainloop(self, func, subthread=False):
        if subthread:
            functuple = tuple(func)
            _thread.start_new_thread(self.mainlooprunnerx, functuple)
        elif not subthread:
            self.mainlooprunner(func)
    . . .

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = PGMaster([1600, 900], pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE)
    # vvv Real codes vvv
    print(pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    print(pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    print(pygame.HWSURFACE)
    print(pygame.OPENGL)
    print(pygame.RESIZABLE)
    print(pygame.NOFRAME)
    # ^^^ Real codes ^^^

    def myloop():
        print('Hello World!')
        return
    root.mainloop(myloop, True)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyGameUI\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
>     root.mainloop(myloop, True)
>   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyGameUI\__init__.py", line 100, in mainloop
>     functuple = tuple(func)
> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
> ```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you wish to achieve, etc. Can you give an example with input and an error message/expected output?

Comment: Don't use anything that starts with underscore. It is python way of marking something as 'protected' and developers don't guarantee its behaviour won't change.

Comment: @gonczor It's deprecated, but I still use it because I don't want to define a nested class - it will decrease code readability. From docs: "thread module was renamed in _thread due to its deprecation".

Comment: What you want is `functuple = (func,)`, i.e. a 1-item tuple

Comment: So you should **all the more** avoid using it!

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I pass it to the thread initalaizer.

Comment: Also remove the `*` from `def mainlooprunnerx(self, *function)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured out. `_thread` is *actually* bad. I have rewritten my code - now I'm using `threading`!

---

I used `tuple(func)` instead of `tuple((func,))`